# Startup disks are disabled after upgrading to OS X El Capitan

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos, dual-boot

Recently I upgraded my Mac mini to OS X El Capitan. After the upgrade completed, I can't select a startup disk in System Preferences -> Startup Disk.

[image]

*BOOTCAMP/Windows* is disabled here. Searching for a solution I came across the following: press and hold the Option key while booting to get all available systems, but that trick didn't work for me. Any solution will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the lock to make changes

[image]

Comment: By this solution every time I need to click this lock. Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: I don't think so. Even with SIP turned off, it still requires admin authority to edit certain System Prefs.

Comment: Why did they make this change? It's an annoying hassle.

Comment: You'd have to ask Apple that.